# Split cab fare proportional to saving made across the board

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-modeling

Interesting dilemma.

I've figured out how to split a cab fare 3 ways (proportional to time, mileage and equally) but I've found that when the cab fare is split proportional to time and mileage, the savings are not spread equally across board (poor rider B).

e.g. in this case the **total fare is $11**, and the **total mileage is 13.8 mi**.

```
Riders                      A                 B                 C
=====================================================================
Time on journey             10 min            19 min            7 min 
Mileage on journey          3.8 mi            7.2 mi            2.8 mi
```

Results below:

```
Method                        Rider A           Rider B            Rider C
==========================================================================
Original fare (no sharing)    $4.00             $5.00              $4.50
Split % to time               $3.10             $5.80              $2.10      
Split % to mileage            $3.05             $5.75              $2.20
Split equally                 $3.70             $3.70              $3.70
```

As splitting % to time/mileage gives a similar result, I was just wondering if it was possible to introduce a 4th method that takes into account the savings made by each passenger somehow and then divides the fare, so that savings are made across the board. How would I express this mathematically?

Comment: The price dropped from \$17.25 to \$11 in two hours, so wait a couple more hours and they can ride for free!

Comment: @HenningMakholm - love how you noticed that!

Comment: As for the question: Of course it is possible to introduce such a fourth method -- indeed, you just did. So I'm unsure what the question actually is. Do you need help carrying out the calculation you have described?

Comment: Yes - I'm struggling to express it mathematically (not my strongest point)

Comment: x @methuselah: Can you find the amount each has to pay in this particular example? If your goal is to describe the strategy _in general_, then I suspect your problem is that you have too high standards about what "express it mathematically" means; what you have already written is a perfectly cromulent specification of the strategy.

Comment: Ok let's say for instance in the `split % to time` case, rider A makes a saving of 0.90, rider B has to pay 0.80 extra and rider C saves 2.40. I'm looking for a "post calculation" that will offset this, maybe for example remove the savings `(0.9-0.8+2.40)= 2.5` then spread that value across the 3 riders so that it adds up to roughly $11, not sure if my logic there is correct. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any one right answer, but taking the original individual fares as the basis, and subtracting the savings proportionally, may work.  The individual fares, one would hope, would encompass all factors for the cost of the trip for all concerned, and hence would make any joint savings achieved as fair as they could be.

Sum of individual fares:  $\$13.50$

Combined fare:  $\$11.00$

Total savings:  $\$2.50$

Rider A's fraction of the savings:  $4/13.50 \times \$2.50 = \$0.74$

Rider B's fraction of the savings:  $5/13.50 \times \$2.50 = \$0.93$

Rider C's fraction of the savings:  $4.5/13.50 \times \$2.50 = \$0.83$

Rider A's discounted fare:  $\$3.26$

Rider B's discounted fare:  $\$4.07$

Rider C's discounted fare:  $\$3.67$

They all save money, and in proportion to what their trip would have cost individually.  The ordering of the list doesn't change, either; B still pays the most, and A pays the least.

Comment: This is the same as splitting the total cost proportionally to the original fares.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another interpretation of the specification would be simply to split the savings evenly.

Single rides would have cost $4+5+4.50=13.50$, so since the actual price is only $11$ there's a total saving of $2.50$, which is 83 cents per passenger.

So they should pay \$3.17, \$4.17, and \$3.67, respectively.